# Add different criteria and group them by sector

Tags: r

[image]

I'm new to R and I want to group the industry and then add the O-V-G and N / A per the variable in the yellow box. How can I do this efficiently, and should I use a summary?

Im using this librarys at the moment

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(readxl)

df <- read_xlsx("Testdata.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(Industry) %>%
  summarize_at(vars(var1, var2, var3, etc.), funs(sum(!is.na(.))))
```

Comment: ```{r opgave-1-aanpassing}
df %>%  
  group_by(Branche) %>% 
summarise_at(Kwaliteitsbeoordeling, Algemene_indruk)

```   Error in check_dot_cols(.vars, .cols) : object 'Kwaliteitsbeoordeling' not found

Comment: you need to add 'vars' to your code: `df %>% group_by(Branche) %>% summarise_at(vars(Kwaliteitsbeoordeling, Algemene_indruk), funs(sum(!is.na(.))))`